# How do I prevent jitter between moving kinematic platform and a dynamic body in Box2D?

Tags: c++, box2d, game-physics

I've a moving platform (kinematic body), which goes up from it's initial position.

```
b2BodyDef platformDef;
platformDef.type = b2_kinematicBody;
platformDef.linearVelocity = b2Vec2(0.f, 0.5f);
```

Now I've a ball (dynamic body) which the player controls, and it can take a ride on the aforementioned platform to go up from it's position. Here's the ball's data:

```
b2BodyDef ballDef;
ballDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
ballDef.fixedRotation = true;
b2Body *ball = b2dWorld.CreateBody(&ballDef);
b2FixtureDef fixDef;
fixDef.shape = &shapeCircle;  // a simple b2CircleShape with radius 0.6m
fixDef.density = 1.f;
fixDef.friction = 0.2f;
fixDef.restitution = 0.3f;
ball->CreateFixture(&fixDef);
```

Now the ball rightly travels atop the moving platform, while there's a slight jitter of the ball's body throughout the travel i.e. it continuously collides with the platform on which it's moving. I've tried setting the ball's restitution to 0, to no avail.

The pixel to metre ratio of the system is 0.02, if this detail is needed.

Comment: Are you talking about a visibly noticeable jitter, or just that you get a lot of BeginContact/EndContact callbacks? If the latter, there may be nothing you can do about that. If you need to know when the ball is on the platform, you might have to put another slightly larger fixture onto the ball body as a sensor to detect when it's on the platform. If you are talking about a visibly noticeable jitter I would be a little surprised. I have done basically the same thing but found no jitter (see ball on top of platform in far right: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXovY2KTing )

Comment: @iforce2d: Well, I'm taking about the 1st i.e. visibly noticeable jitter :( And yes, I'm surprised too, have you set a lower value for gravity vector and is the platform a kinematic body?

Comment: yes, kinematic with normal gravity. You can find the source for that if you follow the link in description. Are your objects really small? Telling us the PTM doesn't help without some actual sizes as well :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best solution would be one of two weld joints between the two bodies.

If the body is "static" on the platform (not moving side to side), then create a weld joint between the ball and the platform while the ball is on the platform.

If the ball can move from side to side, create a prismatic joint between the two, with the direction of the joint parallel to the platform.

I have used a similar technique to make spiders walk around asteroids ([here](http://nonlinearideas.com/state-of-the-art/)).

**The real idea to take away from this is that there are tools in the physics engines that you can use to really enhance the experience behind the scenes that are not always in play for the simulation.  Use the logic of the situation to change the dynamics.**

In this case, being on or off the platform means you have have to connect or disconnect some other mechanism to provide a better experience.

The engine can handle it.  In the example above, the joints used for walking around the bodies are changed at every vertex on the asteroid's bounding hull.